# Visual Studio specific project not being built when build Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, msbuild

In vs2015 a specific project under solution is not being built when building the solution (the build is not called).

1. In the configuration manager the project is checked-in all the configurations (Release, build and etc..)
2. In options "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is checked.
3. Changes made to the project

When building the project explicitly new files are being built (Not all up to date)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to right-click on the solution file on the Solution Explorer-->Add-->Existing Project-->and then select the `xxx.vcxproj` file of your specific project. Then, the project will be imported into your solution and can be built with the solution. That is the common way and if you do not use this way, please share your method about how you imported the project into your solution.

Comment: Thanks, it was a good idea but I already did it..

Comment: you could also try to share your build log of the solution with us. Also, share a small sample with us to troubleshoot the issue quickly if necessary.

Comment: Doe this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495253/12450747](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495253/12450747)? Close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder of the solution folder, does this work?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thanks but no and that was pretty "heavy" recovery took time and was not smooth, so keep in mind if someone will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following steps:

**1)** reset all vs settings under Tools-->Import and Reset Settings-->Reset all settings

**2)** disable any third party vs installed extensions under **Tools**-->**Extensions and Updates**

**3)** delete all caches files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages` and

`C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

And then restart VS, delete the specific project on the solution explorer of VS2015. And then readd the project by Right-click on the solution-->Add-->Existing Project--> select the `xxx.csproj` file of the specific project to add into the solution.

**Then**, you can build the solution to check whether project is built.

**Besides**, you could try [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) on the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 to start a pure, initial vs to test your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I will try and update!

Comment: Any feedback will be expected!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I did step 1 and 3 (2 was a bit overkill for me) added again the .csproj  marked in the "project dependencies" and tadam magic. 
Thanks again :)